# $rootScope.$broadcast on $rootScope.$on: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angularjs, events, event-handling, angularjs-scope, angularjs-rootscope

I want to define page title in angular like this :

a standard `PageController` :

```
angular.module('admin').controller('AdminController',
    function($scope) {

        // emit an event to rootscope
        $scope.$emit('setPageTitle','Administration');
    }
);
```

then in a run block :

```
angular.module('core').run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('setPageTitle',function(evt,title){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('setPageTitle',title);   // The error is thrown from this line
    });
});
```

and finnally in the `PageHeaderController` :

```
angular.module('core').controller('PageHeaderController',
    function($scope) {

        $scope.$on('setPageTitle',function(evt, title){
            $scope.pageTitle = title;
        });
    }
);
```

This way, I don't need to inject `$rootScope` in each `PageController`, but just `$scope` that is often use for other tasks.

But I get this error at the line marked above in the second code block

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

What is wrong here ? I don't see what cause an infinit loop here because I think I just make theses steps :

- Emit from child
- Handle in rootscope and broadcast to children
- Handle in a specific child

Comment: change the 'setPageTitle' event name to different  name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the '`setPageTitle`' event name to a different name should work, try like this

```
angular.module('core').run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('setPageTitle',function(evt,title){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('setPageTitleCtrl',title);   // The error is thrown from this line - changed 'setPageTitle' to 'setPageTitleCtrl'
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('core').controller('PageHeaderController',
    function($scope) {

        $scope.$on('setPageTitleCtrl',function(evt, title){
            $scope.pageTitle = title;
        });
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason here is that $rootScope has the ability to catch events which broadcasted by itself. Thus the infinity loop happened.

[Here's a very clear explanation on $rootScope's $emit, $broadcast, $on behavior](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/#rootscopeemit-versus-rootscopebroadcast)

Answer (score 1):

```
$rootScope.$on('setPageTitle',function(evt,title){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('setPageTitle',title);   // The error is thrown from this line
});
```

Is this the cause? Try giving distinct event names by to trace direction.